# Remove block area from dhtmlx scheduler

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using DHTMLX Scheduler for booking an appointments. To avoid a double booking I have shown a block on a time slot which has already been selected by some other user but yet to be done with appointment process.

I have setInterval to check the status of appointment which is currently in process by some other users.

What I want is if I get some data in setInterval that particular block should be removed. Following is a script that I am using to show block and other appointments on scheduler.

```
// This is how I'm showing block area on scheduler

scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({  
     start_date: new Date(2013,11,29,01,00),
     end_date: new Date(2013,11,29,01,10),
     css: "inprocess",
     sections: {
     unit: 'a7b6e635-f62f-6f12-020f-52a959d1ca47'
  }
});

// This is how I'm showing appointments on scheduler

scheduler.config.multi_day = true;
scheduler.init('scheduler_here',new Date(2013,11,29),"unit");
scheduler.parse([{"start_date":"2013-12-29 01:13","end_date":"2013-12-29 01:23","text":"<div style='float: left;'>Booked<\/div><div style='float: right;
scheduler.updateView();
```

The sections which are inprocess I wish to update per five seconds which is why I have call setInterval. Im getting same data in json as inprocess from setInterval. I wish to update that particular section. It could be add more block area which are in process or remove existing blocks.

Well I already know how can I add more blocks, I'm stuck at how can I remove existing block areas/in process areas.

*I don't want to update whole sections for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [deleteMarkedTimespan](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_deletemarkedtimespan.html) method. It takes the same parameters as .addMarkedTimespan and can be used to remove marked/blocked areas from specific times. You can test it on this [sample page](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/09_api/03_highlighted_timespans.html)

execute following code in browser console, it should remove a part of marked area on Monday of the initial week:

```
scheduler.deleteMarkedTimespan({
    start_date: new Date(2012, 7, 6, 0), 
    end_date: new Date(2012, 7, 6, 3)
}); 
scheduler.updateView();//redraw the scheduler
```

related docs:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/limits.html#removingmarkingblocking